# Redirection, subtitute or rewrite

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite, rewrite, mod-proxy

we have a homepage hosted by another provider in amazon, we are developing and event related page, due a SEO needs we need a redirection from http://www.example.com/event (hosted on amazon, out of our control) to http://event.example.com (hosted on our servers), but we need that the url on the user browser maintains http://www.example.com/event showing the content of http://event.example.com.

The web page develop by us in http://event.example.com is an .net IIS page, so we guess that between amazon page and our .net page we need an apache reverse proxy and probably mod_substitute/mod_rewrite help, what would be the necessary apache rules? Also any other suggestion as IIS rewrite approach would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What about an IFRAME?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "out of our control"? Obviously, if you have _no control_ of `http://www.example.com/event` (or at least the `www.example.com` host) then you can't do anything. (?)

Comment: Sorry, I mean we does not manage this service, they only do a redirection. Unless you want to say that this server is the one that should take care of the rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sorry, I mean we does not manage this service, they only do a redirection.

A "redirection" (as in an *external redirect*) is presumably not desirable for SEO reasons. An IFRAME (as @bjoster suggests) would require control of the content (at `www.example.com/event`) but again is probably not desirable from an SEO point of view.

To implement a *reverse proxy* requires *considerable* control of `www.example.com`, which you don't appear to have. mod_substitute/mod_rewrite are not really going to help you; you need a reverse proxy.

Unless you can intercept the request between the user and `www.example.com/event` (eg. you control an intermediary proxy server in a closed network) then you need "control" of `www.example.com/event`.

> Also any other suggestion as IIS rewrite approach would be appreciated.

The user never even gets to your IIS server.

By the sounds of it, an *external redirect* is your only option, if you want to serve the content from `http://event.example.com` - but the URL in the browser will naturally change to `http://event.example.com`.